# If statement is true, script returns console.log() inside block but not return

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be maximally concise so my post will be mostly code. I see that is somehow against rules, but I think it is easiest way for you to see problem if you paste code in console. I don't get it why if statement returns console.log() for validIn function but not return false which is in same block.

So function checkSudo works fine separately:

```
function checkSudo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i < data.length - 1 && data[i].length !== data[i + 1].length) {
        console.log("hello");
        return false;
      }
      if (
        i < data.length - 1 &&
        data[i].toString() === data[i + 1].toString()
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      let sortRows = data[i].sort((x, y) => x - y);
      let compare = [...new Set(sortRows)];
      if (sortRows.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let columns = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        columns.push(data[i][j]);
        columns.sort((x, y) => x - y);
        let compare = [...new Set(columns)];
        if (columns.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

but inside isValid function only shows console.log (???)

```
function isValid(data) {
  if (data.length == 1 && data[0] != 1) {
    return false;
  }
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  checkSudo(data);
  function checkSudo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i < data.length - 1 && data[i].length !== data[i + 1].length) {
        console.log("hello");
        return false;
      }
      if (
        i < data.length - 1 &&
        data[i].toString() === data[i + 1].toString()
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      let sortRows = data[i].sort((x, y) => x - y);
      let compare = [...new Set(sortRows)];
      if (sortRows.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let columns = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        columns.push(data[i][j]);
        columns.sort((x, y) => x - y);
        let compare = [...new Set(columns)];
        if (columns.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

array (which returns false) for calling function(s):

```
[
  [1, 2, 4, 2,3],
  [3,2, 4,1],

  [4,1, 3,2],
  [2,3, 1,4]
];
```

What the *beep* is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to return checkSudo?

```js
function isValid(data) {
  if (data.length == 1 && data[0] != 1) {
    return false;
  }
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  // add return
  return checkSudo(data);
  function checkSudo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i < data.length - 1 && data[i].length !== data[i + 1].length) {
        console.log("hello");
        return false;
      }
      if (
        i < data.length - 1 &&
        data[i].toString() === data[i + 1].toString()
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      let sortRows = data[i].sort((x, y) => x - y);
      let compare = [...new Set(sortRows)];
      if (sortRows.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let columns = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        columns.push(data[i][j]);
        columns.sort((x, y) => x - y);
        let compare = [...new Set(columns)];
        if (columns.toString() !== compare.toString()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

var dataz = [
  [1, 2, 4, 2,3],
  [3,2, 4,1],

  [4,1, 3,2],
  [2,3, 1,4]
]

console.log(isValid(dataz))
```